# How to load/link dynamically DLL which was already referenced in project (copy local false)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll

In resume, we want to use the CefSharp dll to embed a browser in our .NET app.
We don't want to add size to our setup since the dll size is quite large.
Here is what i try to do :

1. I reference the DLL in my project as Copy local to false which when
   compiling will not link the DLL in the files.
2. Before using the cefsharp class in my code i download the DLL plus all the file needed and extract it where the app .exe is located
3. This is where i hit a wall, if i try to use the cefsharp class after everything is done at the good place the cefsharp will not work
   which is normal because the dll have not been loaded (unless an app restart).

Is there a way
    to dynamically link my **already referenced dll** in memory, so i don't
    have to restart my application?
Thanks !

Comment: This can be difficult and it may not work.  You can use [AppDomain.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58(v=vs.110).aspx) to load the downloaded assembly into memory, but there are sometimes issues with load contexts which require further hand holding of the appdomain when locating types.  But you might luck out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restarting my app...